# is the statement "We ain't never" positive?

Tags: meaning, negation, abbreviations

This might be an odd question.

A lyric of popular song, "We ain't never getting older".
I understand as "ain't never" is double negatives and when two negative elements cancel each others, I know it is positive statement.

Here, Does this statement mean "we are getting older?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double negatives are sometimes used to intensify the negativity.

I imagine that this is likely one such case. The statement actually means, "We aren't getting older".

It can be difficult to tell whether the double negative is meant to be taken as a positive inversion or as an intensifier. The key is often found in the context.

Comment: Here's an english stack exchange post that's pretty educational too

http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31667/are-double-negatives-ever-appropriate-in-english